# Error en instacia

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Buen día.

Al abrir la aplicacion de visual studio me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Error en la Instancia]

si le doy continue abre la app y puedo usarla sin ningun problema.

El detail es el siguiente:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at DiagnosticoPruebas.Cap_PruebasDataSetTableAdapters.UsuariosTableAdapter.Fill(UsuariosDataTable dataTable) in C:\Users\gdjgrico\Documents\Capturador y formulario\CapturadorPruebas\DiagnosticoPruebas\Cap_PruebasDataSet.Designer.vb:line 782
   at DiagnosticoPruebas.Login.Login_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\gdjgrico\Documents\Capturador y formulario\CapturadorPruebas\DiagnosticoPruebas\Login.vb:line 60
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

La cadena de coneccion es la siguiente:

`Data Source=GDJF04973\GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=f5;Password=f5report`

y el servidor es el siguiente:

[image: Servidor]

espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos...

Comment: Puedes utilizar el servidor también??, el servidor está en el mismo pc o es remoto?

Comment: @harifo el servidor es remoto. y no entiendo la primera pregunta.

Comment: Te explico, ese error ocurre cuando la instancia del servidor se encuentra caída y la puedes levantar por consola si es que no tiene otro error, pero para este caso aún falta que agregues detalles, como la cadena de conexión y la versión de tus software. Completa la publicación para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Amplia además, la parte de "details" que aparece ahí. Todo sirve

Comment: @harifo version del sofware es SQL Server 18. la cadena de coneccion es la siguiente:  `Data Source=GDJF04973\GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=f5;Password=********` y el detail es el siguiente:

Comment: @harifo ya agregue el detail.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102353/discussion-between-giovanni-and-harifo).

Answer (score 0):

Econtre la solucion al error comentando la siguiente linea:

```
    Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'Cap_PruebasDataSet.Usuarios' 
        Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
    **'Me.UsuariosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Cap_PruebasDataSet.Usuarios)**
     Me.UsernameTextBox.Clear()
     Me.PasswordTextBox.Clear()
     Me.UsernameTextBox.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comentando la linea que esta en asteriscos,cuando carga el formulario.